# How to handle multiple-currency and custom quote item price on Magento?

Tags: event-observer, quote

I have a magento store with two currency, and my items in cart have a dynamic price. I succesfully calculate my quote_item price, with an observer and setCustomPrice and setOriginalCustom price.

```
$quoteItem->setCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($price);
$quoteItem->getProduct()->setIsSuperMode(true);
$quote->save();
```

Comment: I had same problem but i found a way to do this given in below link. [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827188/magento-custom-price-value-not-converting-by-changing-currency/38243913 ](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37827188/magento-custom-price-value-not-converting-by-changing-currency/38243913)

Answer (score 2):

HI you need to always convert the price to base price currency because of setCustomPrice() always work on base currency.

```
$baseCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getBaseCurrencyCode(); 
$currentCurrencyCode = Mage::app()->getStore()->getCurrentCurrencyCode();

 if($baseCurrencyCode==$currentCurrencyCode):
// convert price from current currency to base currency
$baseprice= Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $currentCurrencyCode, $baseCurrencyCode); 
 else:
// convert price from base currency to current currency
$baseprice= Mage::helper('directory')->currencyConvert($price, $baseCurrencyCode, $currentCurrencyCode); 
endif;

    $quoteItem->setCustomPrice($baseprice);
    $quoteItem->setOriginalCustomPrice($baseprice);
```

Comment: Hi amit  am sourav . please can you  come online at skype.

Comment: checkout_cart_product_add_after am using the this event

Comment: Fatal error: Call to a member function getCode() on a non-object in F:\xamp\htdocs\magento1.9.1\app\code\core\Mage\Directory\Model\Currency.php on line 206 this error occuring

Comment: check currency rate set in amdin

Comment: alredy set in currency rate  option